# Validation Application block and model localization

Tags: .net, validation, localization, validation-application-bl

I can use **ErrorMessageResourceName** and **ErrorMessageResourceType** to translate rules into my language. But how do I translate class name and properties?

Currently I get something like *Valideringsmeddelande för 'LastName'* as validation message. I want **LastName** to be localized too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorMessageResourceName`, and `ErrorMessageResourceType` properties are not used by Validation Application Block. They are included in Validation Application Block 5.0, because VAB's `BaseValidationAttribute` now inherits from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`. These properties are defined in DataAnnotations' `ValidationAttribute`. By inheriting from DataAnnotations, the applications and frameworks can validate a model without having a dependency on VAB (such as the validation that ASP.NET MVC does for instance).

What you can do is use VAB's `MessageTemplateResourceName` and `MessageTemplateResourceType` and don't use any markers and use a text specific to the property. For instance, put this complete text in your resource: "Valideringsmeddelande för efternamn" (sorry if the translation is crappy; I used Google translate).

---

Update:

I did some digging around in the library and unfortunately there is no easy way around this. Below is the code for the `GetMessage` method that is defined in the `Validator` base class that is located in `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation`.

```
protected internal virtual string GetMessage(
    object objectToValidate, string key)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        this.MessageTemplate, 
        new object[] { objectToValidate, key, this.Tag });
}
```

As you can see, the error message is generated using the `MessageTemplate` as format string together with the `objectToValidate`, `key`, and `Tag` as formatting arguments. The `Tag` is a value that you can define in a `ValidationAttribute` and is therefore static and can not be culture specific. When you are validating a property, the supplied `key` will always be the name of that property. This name will  be supplied by the framework by reflecting over the validated type.

You can make the name more user friendly and language specific, by defining a new `Validator` and overriding the `GetMessage`. This way you can fetch a culture dependent text based on the property name from a resource. The problem is however, that you will have to create a sub class for every validation attribute you wish to use and for each validation attribute you must inherit the supporting validator class. While this shouldn’t be that much code per attribute and per validator, it would still be very painful to maintain such a code base.

I think it would be easier to simply define the complete message including user friendly, language specific name in the resource.

---

Update 2:

I thought of something that might possibly help. When your application only has to be able to display a single language at a time, there may be a work around. This won't work for web applications were the displayed messages are localized based on the thread's current culture, but it might work for desktop applications were you can configure language specific texts in the application's configuration file.

When you define the validation rules in the application's configuration file (which is a model VAB supports), you can use the Tag attribute with a language specific string.

```
<validation>
  <type name="Company.Application.Domain.Person" 
    defaultRuleset="Default"
    assemblyName="Company.Application.Domain">
    <ruleset name="Default">
      <properties>
        <property name="LastName">
          <validator type="StringLengthValidator" tag="efternamn" 
            upperBound="30" lowerBound="1" 
            lowerBoundType="Inclusive" upperBoundType="Inclusive"
            negated="false" messageTemplate=""
            messageTemplateResourceName=""
            messageTemplateResourceType="" 
            name="String Length Validator" />
        </property>
      </properties>
    </ruleset>
  </type>
</validation>
```

Take a close look at the tag `tag="efternamn"`. When you put the {2} placeholder in the format string in your resource, it will get replaced by the string defined in tag. In other words, this resource string:

```
Valideringsmeddelande för '{2}'
```

will result in this validation message:

```
Valideringsmeddelande för 'efternamn'
```

Of course for this to work, your configuration must be localized. This wouldn’t be a good solution for web applications.

But... you can also go one step further and build an `IConfigurationSource` implementation that returns a `ValidationSettings` instance that is based on the thread's current culture. In this scenario you will have to build the configuration in code. Here is an example of how to do this:

```
public class MyConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    private Dictionary<CultureInfo, ValidationSettings> settings =
        new Dictionary<CultureInfo, ValidationSettings>();

    public ConfigurationSection GetSection(string sectionName)
    {
        if (sectionName == ValidationSettings.SectionName)
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            lock (this.settings)
            {
                if (!this.settings.ContainsKey(culture))
                {
                    this.settings[culture] = 
                        this.BuildSettingsFor(culture);
                }
                return this.settings[culture];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private ValidationSettings BuildSettingsFor(
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO: Build up your configuration here. Example:

        new StringLengthValidatorData("LastName_Smaller100")
        {
            Tag = MyResources.GetValue(
                "Customer.LastName", culture),
            LowerBound = 1,
            LowerBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive,
            UpperBound = 100,
            UpperBoundType = RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive
        }
    }
}
```

You can supply an instance of that `MyConfigurationSource` to the `ValidationFactory` or, if you want better integration, hook up this type it in the VAB configuration.

Note however that building validation rules in code is currently a lot of work, especially because VAB does not (yet) have a decent fluent configuration API (I complained about this [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=222714)). I'm in the process of writing an API that makes it much easier to do so (keep an eye on [my blog](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven) for that).

Good luck.

Comment: That's kind of crappy that you need to write a custom message for each validationrule/property pair. :(

Comment: @JGauffin: I think it is wise to ask this at the Entlib Forum: http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/Create.aspx. Perhaps I'm missing one VAB's features. I'll also give it a thought this weekend. Perhaps I can come up with a way around this.

Comment: @JGauffin: Please read my update. I did some digging in the framework.

Comment: I wish I could use my own validation library (http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/06/introducing-a-validation-library/). The client is all MS focused, no open source at all :( But thanks for your excellent answers.

Comment: I can't blame you for writing your own framework. I did the same with my own logging lib (http://loggin.codeplex.com). However, I normally wouldn't advice developers to write their own framework when many are already available (especially not in the boss’s time). Developing and maintaining it is an awful lot of work (I think I speak from experience). A few years back I considered writing my own validation framework, because I thought VAB was overly complex. However, I decided to dig more into VAB and found out that VAB was very flexible. I'm still finding new ways to do things with VAB today.

Comment: Flexibility also has a down side. Problem with VAB is still that it is designed for larger organizations with more complex needs. I took a quick look at you validation framework. It has a few interesting features, such as fluent configuration. This is something I’m currently missing with VAB, but because of the flexibility it is also something that can be added. I’m in the process of writing a blog post about this. Also keep in mind that VAB has integration support for WinForms, WebForms, WCF and WPF. It’s hard to beat this when writing your own.